# Sqoop - FileAlreadyExists exception

Tags: oracle, shell, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I need some help with sqoop.

First of all, I'm sorry, my english isn't very good.

Using the folowing command:

```
sqoop import -D mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=false  --num-mappers 1 --connection-manager "com.quest.oraoop.OraOopConnManager" --connect "jdbc:Oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myserver)(PORT=1534)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myservice)))" --username "rodrigo" --password pwd \
--query "SELECT column1, column2 from myTable where \$CONDITIONS" \
--null-string '' --null-non-string '' --fields-terminated-by '|' \
--lines-terminated-by '\n' --as-textfile --target-dir /data/rodrigo/myTable \
--hive-import --hive-partition-key yearmonthday --hive-partition-value '20180101' --hive-overwrite --verbose -P --m 1 --hive-table myTable
```

My table is already created, because I must create a solicitation for create a table in my hive database, so I can't create dinamically inside sqoop command.

I have permission to create the directory in hdfs.

When I remove the directory, sqoop logs an error saying that I have no create table permissions, and when I already create the diretory, it returns a FileAlreadyExistsException.

What can I do to solve that?

Thanks from Brazil.

Comment: Can you edit and paste the error you're getting ? also do you get the same error when your user tries to create a table directly in Hive ?

Comment: Sqoop, like all Mapreduce jobs, will complain if the destination HDFS directory exists.

Comment: You question is not complete, need more detail. Can you try using --hive-overwrite?

Comment: I solved it, without using the flags  - - target-dir and - - query. So the flag - -warehouse-dir worked fine even if the directory exists